# How to use javascript with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to write with phantomjs
example:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.open('http://www.w3school.com.cn',
function() {
    var res = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElmentsByTagName('a');
    });
    console.log(res);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

runing,error tip:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElmentsByTagName('a')')

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():2
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3
null
```

why?what did i do?

Comment: I don't see `document.getElmentById` in your code but only `getElmentsByTagName`. Both of them have typos. It should be `getElementById` or `getElementsByTagName`. Please show the code that matches the error message.

Comment: Could you try to read the status? Eg: `page.open('...', function(status){
console.log(status);
var res = ...}
);`
And then look at the status, it should be `'success'`. Or was the typo the error?

Comment: as you wish, success .but still report TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function...@AgashThamo.

Comment: I fixed it.Thank you for your correction.check it again,please@ArtjomB.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't calling `phantom.exit();`when Phantomjs is done doing its thing.

Append said command to the end of your script and it should work normally.

Comment: What does a script not ending have to do with an obvious typo. This should have been a comment.